# Core Data - How to disable faulting mechanism

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

Is there any way to tell Core Data to disable its memory management? I have NSManagedObjects in a view that don't get saved to a context for a very long time. The managed objects are in a table view. The user will see that view first, then navigate away to another view, spending lots of time there before returning to the table view. I am getting this exception: “NSObjectInaccessibleException - CoreData could not fulfill a fault”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Core Data fault fulfillment error usually means that you are holding on to an object that has been faulted and another thread has deleted one of the children objects and committed to the persistent store. So when the original thread goes back to fulfill the fault, there isn't anything there anymore.

One of the things you can do is have your other views listen to NSManagedObjectContextDidSave and NSManagedObjectContextWillSave to react to the change as it is occurring (i.e. reload the data fresh), so you don't wind up with bad objects in the cache.

Comment: The thing is that I'm using different contexts for the table view and the another view. These contexts share the same persistent store coordinator. Could what you describe still be what's happening?

Comment: That's a lot worse I think because what's happening is I'm assuming you are deleting objects in one context and they are faulted in the other context. So when the context that has the fault tries to reload them in memory, they are gone and since you are using another context, the deletion did not notify the other context's cache. Are you using two contexts for a particular reason?

Answer (score 4):

To disable faulting when using an NSFetchRequest to get core data entities, just add the line [request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO] before you execute the request.

[Read more details here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html)