# Core Data fetching relationship object

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, one-to-many

I have two entities in my `Core Data` one named `Group` and other named `Group Member` I have set-up a `To-Many` relationship between `Group` and `Group Member` 
I save the data to DB using core data generated function
`addMembers`
But when I fetch the same group from core data, I get 0 results in `Group Member` object.
My `Group Member` object is of type `NSSet` in the class `Group`

Below is the code to store and retrieve data

```
if let members = json["members"] as? [[String:Any]] {

    group.addToMembers(NSSet(array: SPEGroupMember.parseArray(jsonArray: members)))
}
group.save(saveInDB: false)

print("JSON Group Members: \(String(describing: group.members))")

let iSPEGroup = DataQuery.getSPEGroup(byId: group.groupId) as! SPEGroup
for member in iSPEGroup.members?.allObjects as! [SPEGroupMember] {
    print("Fetched group memebers Phone numbers\(String(describing: member.userPhone))")
}
```

In the above snippet when I do `group.members` I get a set of non-zero result but when I do `iSPEGroup.members` I get a set of zero results.

Comment: Add some code showing how you store and fetch `Group` and also explain what you mean with "do not get", is it null or an empty set or do you get an error?

Comment: Please show your code, most possibly its a `Fault` which is an optimization by Core Data to use less memory.

Comment: I just added the code snippet

Comment: is SPEGroup and SPEGroupMember NSManagedObjects?

Comment: Yes they are NSManagedObjects

Comment: `group.save(saveInDB: false)`, what does `false` mean here?

Comment: `group.save(saveInDB: false)` here false means just save the context but do not save it to hard drive now that's all

Comment: Please disable faulting and try. How to disable fault: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639546/core-data-how-to-disable-faulting-mechanism